# Sql query to find rows with exactly two 's' characters

Tags: sql

How can I write a sql query which will return rows from a table (named 'emp') where field 'job' has exactly two 's' characters somewhere within the data.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Awesome how your username perfectly fits to the end of your comment

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM your_Table
WHERE (LENGTH(Field) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Field, 's', '')) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    emp
where   job like '%s%s%'
```

Comment: This will find jobs with at least two 's'.

Comment: it will return not only two but also more than two 's'. i want exactly two 's'

Answer (score 0):

```
select  job
from    emp
where   job like '%s%s%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  jobs
from    emp
where   job like '%s%s%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM emp
 WHERE job LIKE '%s%s%'
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
  FROM emp
 WHERE job LIKE '%s%s%s%';
```